# No matching function call for boost::get in graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm modeling my graph after example `geometry/07_a_graph_route_example` from boost.

My Graph looks like this:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    gG_vertex_property<string, double, pointClass>,
    gG_edge_property<listClass, pointClass>
> graph_type;

graph_type Graph;
```

with `gG_vertex_property` and `gG_edge_property` as custom properties.

Now every time I try to call `dijkstra_shortest_path` with

```
     boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(Graph, endVert,                             // Graph Object, End of Search Object
                                       &predecessors[0], &costs[0],                                             // Vectors to store predecessors and costs
                                       boost::get(boost::edge_weight, Graph),
                                       boost::get(boost::vertex_index, Graph),                                  // Vertex Index Map
                                       std::less<double>(), std::plus<double>(),                                // Cost calculating operators
                                       (std::numeric_limits<double>::max)(), double(),                          // limits
                                       boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>());                         // Visitior, does nothing at the moment
```

as `WeightMap` i get:

> error: no matching function for call to 'get' boost::get(boost::edge_weight, Graph)

And a whole lot of templates for add which do not fit my use case. How i'm reading the docs this is the standard way to do it. Are my properties missing something?

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with your `gG_vertex_property`, which is why a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required.

Comment: I'm watching this space, but still no code details? Are you going to add those, or should we close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `gG_vertex_property` and `gG_edge_property` are "Bundled" properties (there's no so such thing as custom properties). If so, you should pass these instead of "boost::get(boost::edge_weight, Graph)", which tries to access "Internal" properties, completely separate thing. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html . I guess if properties are structs and edge weights are kept in `gG_edge_property::weight`, the correct code would be something like this:

```
 boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(Graph, endVert,                             // Graph Object, End of Search Object
                                   &predecessors[0], &costs[0],                                             // Vectors to store predecessors and costs
                                   get(&gG_edge_property::weight, Graph), /*!!!!!!!!*/
                                   boost::get(boost::vertex_index, Graph),                                  // Vertex Index Map
                                   std::less<double>(), std::plus<double>(),                                // Cost calculating operators
                                   (std::numeric_limits<double>::max)(), double(),                          // limits
                                   boost::dijkstra_visitor<boost::null_visitor>());                         // Visitior, does nothing at the moment
```

Comment: Thank you, i think it works that way.